# Windows 2Gb memory limit

Tags: windows, memory-management, heap-memory

I use a third party test application. 
I give the application the test input and get the results.
If I feed huge data the application it gives "memory allocation error"
When I observe the used memory from task manager I see that it gives the error when the private bytes reach ~2Gb.

I tried it both 32Bit Windows XP and 64Bit Windows 7. The result was the same.

what should I do to increase reserved heap memory form my third party application?
I want it to use more than 2Gb memory.

Comment: If you can use that app both on a 32bits and 64bits machine the **app itself** is a 32 bits app, and those are limited to 2GB of memory, nothing can be done about that.

Answer (score 5):

The third party application is most likely build for 32bit. So you are limited to 2Gb memory usage.

You can try to find if it has an 64bit installation package.

Comment: Yes its 32bit. What if I run it on 64bit OS? Is there a way to use more than 2Gb?

Comment: Nope, if the application is build for 32bit you're stuck on that, check msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366778.aspx

Comment: @Jeoren it says "4 GB with IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE set" How could I use this "IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE" set?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb613473(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I'm going to try it now.

Comment: @zontragon if you don't compile the test app, then its already frozen.